# Best way to clean column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, apply

I have been **trying to clean a particular column** from a dataset. I am using the function .apply() multiple times **in order to throw out any symbol** that could be in in the string values of the column.

For each symbol, here's the function : .apply(lambda x: x.replace("", ""))

Although my code works, it is quite long and not that clean. I would like to know if there is a shorter and/or better manner of cleaning a column.

Here is my code:

```
df_reviews = pd.read_csv("reviews.csv")
df_reviews = df_reviews.rename(columns={"Unnamed: 0" : "index", "0" : "Name"})
df_reviews['name'] = df_reviews["Name"].str.split(':', expand=True)[0]


df_reviews['name'] = df_reviews['name'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("Review", "")).apply(lambda x: x.replace(":", "")).apply(lambda x: x.replace("'", "")).apply(lambda x: x.replace('"', "")).apply(lambda x: x.replace("#", ""))\
                                .apply(lambda x: x.replace("{", "")).apply(lambda x: x.replace("}", "")).apply(lambda x: x.replace("_", "")).apply(lambda x: x.replace(":", ""))



df_reviews['name'] = df_reviews['name'].str.strip()
```

As you can see, the many .apply() functions makes it difficult to clearly see what is getting removed from the "name" column.

Could someone help me ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3):

You can also use **regex**:

```
df_reviews['name'] = df_reviews['name'].str.replace('Review|[:\'"#{}_]', "", regex=True)
```

#### Regex pattern:

```
'Review|[:\'"#{}_]'
```

- `Review` : replace the word "Review"
- `|` : **or**
- `[:\'"#{}_]` - any of these characters within the square brackets `[]`

#### Note:

If you are looking to remove ALL punctuation: you can use this instead

```
import string

df_reviews['name'] = df_reviews['name'].str.replace(f'Review|[{string.punctuation}]', "", regex=True)
```

Which will remove the following characters:

```
!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace('Review| \:| \'|\"|\#| \_', "").str.strip()
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thank you ! Could you explain the expression 'Review| \:| \'|\"|\#| \_'  please ?

Comment: Glad it helped. You can accept and upvote the answers if you find them helpful. Good luck!

Comment: `|` means or. And I prefer to use `\\`   before characters for example ' or " which are the string characters, not to be confused by the python syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```html
import pandas as pd

REMOVE_CHARS = ["Review", ":", "#", "{", "}", "_", "'", '"']
def process_name(name: str) -> str:
    for removal_char in REMOVE_CHARS:
        try:
            print(f"removal char {removal_char}", name.index(removal_char))
            name = name.replace(removal_char,"")
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return name

def clean_code(df_reviews: pd.DataFrame):
    # Renaming `Unnamed: 0` as `index` ; `0` as `Name`
    df_reviews = df_reviews.rename(columns={"Unnamed: 0": "index", "0": "Name"})
    # todo: clarification needed
    # Here Name col contains a words separated by : so `expand=True` separate it into different columns
    # then we just read the zeroth column
    df_reviews['name'] = df_reviews["Name"].str.split(':', expand=True)[0]
    # Preprocessing of name column
    # >> if `name` contains ["Review",":","#","{","}","_","'",'"'] remove/replace it
    df_reviews['name'] = df_reviews['name'].apply(lambda x: process_name(x))
    df_reviews['name'] = df_reviews['name'].str.strip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df_reviews = pd.read_csv("reviews.csv")
```